# how to remove files list and namespaces list from doxygen RTF output

Tags: doxygen

I'm setting up documentation output for my project and I want to generate doxygen RTF output without Namespace list and without file list.

Although If I turn off `SHOW_NAMESPACES` and/or `SHOW_FILES` from the doxygen configuration file the RTF output errors out as:

```
"error: problems opening rtf file files.rtf for reading" 

"error: problems opening rtf namespace namespaces.rtf for reading"
```

How can the RTF output be generated with `SHOW_NAMESPACES` and `SHOW_FILES` OFF?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Any special doxygen layout file used?

Comment: I'm using Doxygen 1.8.15 with no special layouts.

Comment: I think best is to create an issue at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new with a small example.